# Find a match but not if followed by a specific character

Tags: regex

I want to match all repeating spaces in a each line of the text excluding spaces around a specified character.

For example, if I want to find repeating spaces before `#` in this text

```
first    second third
first second    third
first    second #third

first second    #third
first second #    third
#    first second third
```

I am expecting to match multiple spaces in first 3 lines but not to have matches in last 3.

I have tried this: `/(\S\s{2,})(?!\s*#)/g` but that is also matching repeating spaces after `#`
How to write a regex for this case?

Comment: Are you using a programming language, and what is your end goal here?

Comment: I plan to use it for matching repeated spaces in code but not in indentations and around and after #. I will use it in ripgrep (and vs code), grep and python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution with lookarounds:

```
(?<![#\s])\s\s+(?![\s#])
```

The pattern will match any 2+ spaces `\s\s+`, that are:

- not preceeded by either space or # (`(?<![#\s])`)
- not followed by either space or # (`(?![\s#])`)

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/Mqp863/1).

Comment: This works beautifully for described use case. I failed to explain well that I want to find repeating spaces excluding ones before the code (indentations) and all after # in the comment. This solution catches both indentations and repeating spaces within the comment. I have figured out the indentation fix `(?<![#\s]|^)\s\s+(?![\s#])` and I can live with matches in comments

Answer (score 2):

You could match what you want to get out of the way, and keep in a group what you are looking for.

```
(^[^\S\n]+|[^\S\n]*#.*)|[^\S\n]{2,}
```

**Explanation**

- `(` Capture group 1 (to keep unmodified)

  - `^[^\S\n]+` Match 1+ spaces without newlines  from the start of the string
  - `|` Or
  - `[^\S\n]*#.*` Match optional spaces, `#` and the rest of the line
- `)` Close group 1
- `|` Or
- `[^\S\n]{2,}` Match 2 or more spaces without newlines

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hbCTG7/1).

There is no language tagged, but if for example you want to replace the repeating spaces in the first 3 lines with a single space, this is a JavaScript example where you check for group 1.

If it is present, the return it to keep that part unmodified, else replace the match with your replacement string.

Note that `\s` can also match newlines, therefore I have added dashes between the 2 parts for clarity and used `[^\S\n]+` to match spaces without newlines.

```js
const regex = /(^[^\S\n]+|[^\S\n]*#.*)|[^\S\n]{2,}/g;
const str = `first    second third
first second    third
first    second #third
----------------------------------------
    keep the indenting second #third     #fourth  b.
first second    #third
first second #    third these spaces  should not  match
#    first second third`;
console.log(str.replace(regex, (_, g1) => g1 || " "));
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but it did not work for me. I wanted to exclude matching spaces around and after #

Comment: @Alfodr I have updated the code to not match spaces from the start of the string, and not match double spaces after matching `#` If you want to use this in Python, you can use the same logic as in the JavaScript example.

Comment: I am very ignorant with regex expressions and cannot wrap my head around them. I have not tried in python code yet, but in vs code search, the first group(one we want to ignore/allow) is matched too. On the regex test site, that group is matched as expected but still highlighted in different color. Maybe worth to mention is that I am not doing any replacements but only matches and that is why I do not want to get group 1 matched